# Ignoring tap gesture on UIScrollView, on tap on specific words in contained label

Tags: iphone, ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

A `UIScrollView` has a [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) (custom `UILabel`), where scrolling is vertical-only. There is a `UITapGestureRecogniser` on this `scrollView`, that hides the `scrollView` on single tap.
I want this `tapGesture` to work in all cases, except when some specific words are tapped, more specifically, the links in the label's text. How do I ignore these taps?

Comment: Have you tried "locationInView:", it'll check location of gesture where you compare location if it is in range of label.

Comment: I said specific words, not entire label. :)